# How to revert absolute positioned overlay element order?

Tags: html, css, css-position, overlay

I have the following markup:

```css
.slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="div1">sample1</div>
    <div class="div2">sample2</div>
    <div class="div3">sample3</div>
    <div class="div4">sample4</div>
</div>
```

This code makes the **.slider** content **overlay** each other from the last to the first element, so the last is displayed while the others are overloaded.

What I want it just reverts the actual display order.

Comment: why don't you add z-index to individual divs the way you want

Comment: Did you try [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)? I think it should work.

Comment: I'm not using z-index first 'cause i have other **overlays** out of the **.slider** div, and it will force me to also add z-indexes to the others overlays and also because i don't want to use **js**: Since slider content its dynamic it will force me to use **js** to manipulate the z-index. I'm just using **js** to toggle animation classes.

Comment: But i have no alternatives to z-index, so, thanks guys!

Comment: You dont need to use js for z-indexing, css3 has a counter feature
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is delivered by the css `z-index` property. It specifies the z-order which in case of overlapping elements displays the element with the highest z-index value as first.
Have a look here to see the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index